# Regular Expression to match a string, that doesn't end in a certain string

Tags: regex

I an trying to write a regular expression to be used as part of a replace operation.

I have many paths as follows:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\Common.Workflow\Common.Workflow.csproj">
<ProjectReference Include="..\Common.Workflow\Common.Workflow.Interfaces\Common.Workflow.Interfaces.csproj">
<ProjectReference Include="..\Common.Workflow\Common.Workflow.Persistence\Common.Workflow.Persistence.csproj">
<ProjectReference Include="..\Common.Workflow\Common.Workflow.Process\Common.Workflow.Process.csproj">
```

I need to replace the `Common.Workflow\` in all cases except where the it contains `Common.Workflow.csproj`.

I am moving these files as part of a code clean up.

Comment: Do you mean you want to do this in Visual Studio, or programmatically? VS regexes are fundamentally different from .NET regexes.

Comment: Not much, I'm the worlds most hapless regex person :(

Comment: @TimPietzcker I'm not using VS Regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `Common\.Workflow\\(?!Common\.Workflow\.csproj)` with what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Use a negative look-ahead and a negative look-behind, like this:

```
(?<!.*Common.Workflow.csproj)Common.Workflow\\(?!.*Common.Workflow.csproj)
```

Explanation:

- `(?<!.*Common.Workflow.csproj)` means "`Common.Workflow.csproj` must not appear *before* the match
- `(?!.*Common.Workflow.csproj)` means "`Common.Workflow.csproj` must not appear *after* the match"

This regex will prevent matching if `Common.Workflow.csproj` appears *anywhere* in the input (you didn't specify that the negative match only appears after the search)